# I want to convert datetime column with the format of "2019-06-24T22:17:05.000Z" to PST in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to convert datetime column with the format of  "2019-06-24T22:17:05.000Z" to PST in google big query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See query below:

```sql
select datetime(timestamp("2019-06-24T22:17:05.000Z"),"America/Los_Angeles") as pst_time
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `TIMESTAMP` type is tied to UTC. When you convert a TIMESTAMP to some other type that isn't tied to a particular timezone, such as `STRING`, `DATE`, or `DATETIME`, you can specify the timezone for the conversion.

You can consider the below query to convert the `DATETIME` column to PST timezone:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATETIME FROM TIMESTAMP("2019-06-24T22:17:05.000Z")
AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') AS pst_time;
```

**Output:**

[image]